Official document that describes implementation of frequency weighting curves
What would be the official document that describes the frequency response of A, B, C, D and K weightings and the allowed tolerance for these weightings? The document from IEC might have this information but its a paid document and I'd like to be certain before I purchase it. Could someone please point out an official reference for this?

It's IEC 61672. I believe part one has the actual definitions of the curved and part 2 has the verification procedures. Wikipedia has a good article and the most common analog implementation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting

Also relevant: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36077/design-of-a-digital-a-weighting-filter-with-arbitrary-sample-rate
