# IIR filter design for "data-aided" least-squares filtering

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, least-squares

Consider a discrete-time signal consisting of a desired signal component and noise, as follows.

$$y_k=d_k + n_k,  \qquad k\in\{0,1,\dots,K-1\}$$

This signal is applied to a linear time-invariant (LTI) filter with the goal of recovering the desired signal.  In a "data-aided" scenario, where the desired signal is known *a priori*, coefficients of an FIR filter of length $L \ll K$ filter can be determined easily via linear least-squares

$$\hat{\bf w} = \arg\min_{\bf w} \left\| {\bf d} - {\bf Y w} \right\|_2^2$$

where ${\bf w}$ is a length-$L$ column vector of FIR filter coefficients, $\bf d$ is a column vector of desired signal samples, and $\bf Y$ is a Hankel matrix built from the received data sequence, $y_k$ such that $\bf Yw$ implements the convolution. Is there an easy extension of this least-squares data-aided solution for the design of a (stable) IIR filter of prescribed numerator and denominator transfer function orders?

Comment: The procedure here is trying to build a filter that best "matches" a finite length signal, with the filter (ideally) being shorter than the desired signal.  The notion of wanting an infinite length (IIR) filter to best "match" a finite length signal seems wrong to me.  I suppose the simplest thing to try is to determine the FIR using the given procedure above, and then see if you can find a IIR equivalent representation of the FIR (which is probably not possible except in special cases).  What's the real goal here?  Is the FIR too computationally intensive in the time domain?

Comment: For starting from an FIR and designing an IIR to approximate the FIR, there is this answer that may be helpful: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/27097/28112

Comment: And it looks like this paper might actually be an algorithm of the type you requested: https://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco1998/sessions/Th%20A/ThA%20P-7/1909/MCLANG98.PDF

Although you have to choose some method to convert the desired signal, $d$ into a desired frequency response  $D\left(e^{jw}\right)$.

Comment: @AndyWalls Yes, this is something I had thought about--solving the FIR problem for a length $K$ filter (maximum length for full column rank in $\bf Y$) and then converting the filter to IIR through some kind of arbitrary frequency response fitting method of the type you referenced.
In lieu of some more direct approach (which was what motivated my question) this seems like a reasonable approach.  Thanks!