# low pass filter with minimal ringing

Tags: lowpass-filter, filtering

I am trying to filter out some square wave signal to within a limited band (1/4 or 1/8 of the original), I realized that there's a lot of ringing in the wave when I use my filter (elliptical), I also tried Butterworth, and others (given in Matlab fir1, and classic iir filters) but the only filter that seems to give no ringing is Gaussian. So my question is, how should I go about designing a LPF with minimal ringing? (preferred characteristics: minimal pass band ripple, stop band of more than -50dB, relatively fast roll off). Also as I am trying to implement this in a DSP, low order filters such as IIR types are preferred.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: if the poles are real, not complex-conjugate, then the impulse response (and step response) does not ring.  this means, for a biquad IIR, that the Q must be no greater than 1/2.  but you won't get the roll-off you want with low Q, i'm afraid.  whether it's IIR or FIR, a sharp transition means ringing at the frequency of approximately that of the sharp transition.

Comment: @Robert Are there any optimal IIR filters where we can optimize for Order, Transition band, PB & SB ripples like Parks-McClellan for FIR filters?

Comment: oh i dunno.  i thought Prony was a method to design the impulse response of an IIR to be what you want.  as far as frequency-domain design with brick-walls and the transition band and PB and SB, i guess you might want to look into Elliptical filters.  they be pretty ugly in the time-domain (like horribly non-constant group delay).  oh, and there is Greg Berchin's [FDLS](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/berchins-fdls-arbitrary-filter-design-algorithm) for frequency-domain design.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks for the advice, according to what you said, wouldn't it mean that the ringing is caused solely by the absence of high frequency components, since a slower roll off would allow more high frequency components (attenuated), and if it is the case, is there to design a filter that would minimize the amplitude of the ringing at least?

Comment: ringing need not happen at high frequencies. unless you're using Planck units (or some other natural system of units), frequency is relative anyway.  ringing is caused by an imaginary component in your poles.  with real coefficients and real signal values in your filter, poles and zeros are either purely real or the come in complex-conjugate pairs.  if the latter, your impulse response will have an exponentially-damped sinusoid in it.  having as rapid step response as possible without ringing usually has real poles coincident on top of each other.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I read some more info regarding ringing in relation to poles, and sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can see how the ringing is represented by complex conjugate in poles, however, in FIR filter, there is no poles, but ringing exists regardless of the FIR or IIR. Does this mean that there are poles hidden or cancelled out in FIR filters which would represent ringing?

Comment: well, if your FIR is long enough, you can make your FIR $h[n]$ be whatever you want, including something that rings (as long as the FIR is, note the "F").  with an IIR, it theoretically rings forever (if the poles are complex-conjugate) hence the "I" in IIR.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Thanks for the info. As I am still learning about ringing, would it be correct to summarize that ringing in this scenario is due to: 1) Gibb's Phenomenon when higher harmonics of the square are cut off. 2) complex conjugates in poles (which causes continuous ringing). 3) ringing due to the design in zeros (ex. using window design method where the ideal filter is a sinc function in time domain). Apart from these three causes, are there any other factors that contribute to ringing?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Sorry for the further questions, but I would also like to ask for pulse-shaping filters (Gaussian filter), they seem to round the edges in time domain, however in frequency domain, it is seen as a filter with a long transition band with significant attenuation in the passband, would it be correct to conclude that long transition bands tends to create less ripples in the time domain of the filter? (a side question is if the pulse shaping filters are the digital version of tuning a under-damped circuit to be over-damped?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the amount of ringing that you get is a function of the steepness of the filter in the frequency domain, regardless of filter type. 
At the same steepness an Elliptic will require a lower order but will have pretty much the same ringing as a Butterworth.

Choosing between a linear phase or minimum phase will change the character but not the extent of the ringing.

No matter how you slice it, a square wave contains a lot of high frequencies and once you filter those out, it's not a square wave any more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was wondering based on the characteristics of different phases, is it possible to find a filter which has the preferred roll off, stop band, and pass band with minimal peaks in the ringing? I would rather the ringing last longer but the amplitude of the ringing is smaller